# Django, tutorial - error: No module named urls

Tags: python, django

Hi I am following the tutorial to make first web app by Django([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view))
But I was given this error:

```
 File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
   File "c:\Python27\Proj\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name) ImportError: No module named urls
```

I have read some answers here on SO, but they suggest that this error is caused by wrong version of framework, which is not my case.  My version of python is 2.7 and Djanog 1.10.1

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include


from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))    ]
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

File: polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

EDIT 2:

Thank all for your comments. There is my file structure of the project.

[image]

Comment: Your error might be in `polls.urls`. Can you add that, are you sure that you have that app `polls` and in there is a file named `urls.py`

Comment: Can you add your file structure for this project?

Answer (score 2):

`url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))`

What this line is doing is it's adding the `urls.py` of `polls` app folder, to your urls and also appending `polls/` in front of all.

**Coming to the error :**

```
File "c:\Python27\Proj\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))
```

The error says that it's not able to find that `urls.py` in `polls` folder, so make sure it's there. and properly configured as well.

And also make sure the following :

- your app polls listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` of `settings.py`
- confirm that there is an `__init__.py` file in your `polls` app folder

Comment: Yes, I have the file  urls.py in folder "polls". Please see update.

Comment: @Marek is your app `polls` listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` of `settings.py`

Comment: and can you also confirm that there is an `__init__.py` file in your `polls` app folder?

Comment: polls is listed in INSTALLED_APPS and __init__.py is in my polls app folder. See my second edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem and after spending quite sometime, I have been able to understand that "no module named urls" has got nothing to do with python dependencies or libraries.

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))
```

The line above shows that 'polls' is an app of the project and Django is actually looking for a file named 'urls.py'. Make sure to use the **exact name** of the url matcher file as in the app folder.

For example, if the file has been named as 'url.py', remember to write the exact name as

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.url'))
```

As in Django 1.10, you do not have to worry about anything else.